# Decode SBE message from multiple buffers

Tags: java, streaming, nio

What if message is too big or somehow located on both sides of the stitch of buffers.
here is example

```
DirectByteBuffer buffer1 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(128);
DirectByteBuffer buffer2 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(128);
channel.read(buffer1);
channel.read(buffer2);
Car car = new Car();
car.wrap(buffer1, 256); //????
```

Now assume that `Car` object is in both buffers, the beginning is in `buffer1` and the end in the `buffer2`.
How can i use SBE for streaming objects which may be inevitably located in different chunks, because of streaming nature of protocol?

PS.
Possible way is to create one more buffer with size needed to hold the message and copy both chunks into it, but this seems inefficient for me. 
Thanks

Comment: The real question is why are you doing it this way in the first place? There is no guarantee that the data will be split between the buffers in any particular way, *unless* there were more than 128 bytes available to be read when you issued the first read. Use a single buffer of 256 bytes, or more.

Comment: this is not correct assumption, your write side may write messages with different length into the channel, but on the read side most of the time we use fixed length buffer to read chunks and then apply framing to extract messages.